# Filtro com NSPredicate com herança

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Eu tenho uma estrutura no **Core Data** assim:

```
Cliente
--- id = inteiro
--- dados = Pessoa

Pessoa
--- nome = string

PessoaFisica < Pessoa
--- cpf = string

PessoaJuridica < Pessoa
--- cnpj = string
```

Como eu posso filtrar **Cliente** baseado nos documentos dependendo do tipo de pessoa? Por exemplo, buscar um cliente de acordo com o **cpf**.

Se eu fizer direto assim, ele não entende a herança e diz que não encontrou **cpf** em **Pessoa**:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dados.cpf = %@", cpf];
```

Precisava de uma espécie de *"casting"* de **dados** para **PessoaFisica**. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro usar o sistema de blocos:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    Cliente *cliente = evaluatedObject;
    PessoaFisica *pessoa = cliente.dados;
    return [pessoa isKindOfClass:[PessoaFisica class]] && [pessoa.cpf isEqualToString:cpf];
}];
```

O truque está em `[pessoa isKindOfClass:[PessoaFisica class]]`, que retorna `YES` casso `pessoa` seja uma instância de `PessoaFisica`.

Também existe o método `isMemberOfClass:`. A diferença dos dois é que `isMemberOfClass:` só retorna `YES` se `pessoa` for realmente do tipo `PessoaFisica`, se for uma sub classe já retornará `NO`. Enquanto `isKindOfClass:` retorna `YES` se `pessoa` for do tipo `PessoaFisica` ou de uma sub classe.

Espero que ajude ;)